# Creating a transition matrix from wikipedia clickstream data

Tags: r, matrix, transition, markov-chains

I'm trying to create a transition matrix from the Wikipedia Clickstream dataset. With this, I'd like to show the probability that users transit from one Wikipedia article to another.

I have a dataframe, consisting of three columns. The source.category refers to the title of the source article and the target.category refers to the title of the target article. The third column is "total" and refers to the number of clicks (i.e. the number of times users have moved from that source article to the target article).

From this, I would like to calculate the transition probabilities of going from a source article to a target article given the number of clicks.

Here is a summary of my data frame:

```
source.category    target.category        total      
 Length:98          Length:98          Min.   :   21  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:  684  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median : 2132  
                                       Mean   : 5395  
                                       3rd Qu.: 5296  
                                       Max.   :53378
```

Would the best way be to create a function?

trans.matrix <- function(...)

How would this function look like?

And then fit it in: trans.matrix(as.matrix(df)) ?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using the `reshape2` package. I created a minimal dataset to illustrate this:

```
set.seed(42)

dataset <- expand.grid(letters[1:4], LETTERS[1:4])
dataset$total <- rpois(16, 1)

names(dataset) <- c("source.category", "target.category", "total")
# set the last row to the first row to illustrate fill and aggregate
dataset[16, ] <- dataset[1, ]
```

Then just use the `acast` function to create the matrix, finally normalise the row sums to 1.

```
require(reshape2)

# reshape to wide format
res <- acast(
  dataset, # the dataset
  source.category ~ target.category, # the margins of the result
  value.var = "total", # which variable should be in the cells
  fill=0L, # fill empty cells with this value
  fun.aggregate = sum # aggregate double cells with this function
  )

# normalize rowSums to 1
res <- res / rowSums(res)

# this is your result
res
```

Edit: on larger datasets, this will take forever or even fail. For larger datasets use sparse matrices, from the `Matrix` package, this is way faster and gives a result that is way smaller in storage.

```
require(Matrix)

dataset$target.category <- factor(dataset$target.category)
dataset$source.category <- factor(dataset$source.category)

res <- sparseMatrix(
  as.integer(dataset$target.category),
  as.integer(dataset$source.category),
  x = dataset$total
)

res <- res/rowSums(res)
```

This is fast enough on the whole dataset to work interactively.